# How many experiments we should run to have one success with probability at least $50\%$?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Could you tell me if my reasoning is right? I'm new in probability so I'm still not secure of how I should use the classical distributions to model problems.

My problem is the following: I have a success-failure experiment such that the probability of success is $p\in(0,1)$ ($p$ is supposed to be very little, but this shouldn't change the reasoning). If we run the experiment one time, the probability of success is $p$. If we run the experiment $n$ times, the probability of having $k$ successes is $\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$, for $0\leq k\leq n$. This is modeled by the binomial distribution.

What I want to know is an inverse problem, we can say. How many experiments we should run to have one success with probability at least $50\%$? I'm looking for the minimal number $n$ of experiments.

**My idea:** We can keep $n$ unknown and ask for the probability of having at least one success in $n$ experiments. This is given by $\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$. It's possible to use some program to find the minimum $n$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\geq \frac{1}{2}$. In fact, I did this for some values of $p$, in particular, for $p=\frac{1}{10000}$ we have $n=6932$.

But I'm not sure of this argument. I was looking for the number of experiments necessary to have **one** success with probability at least $50\%$, but ended up calculating the number of experiments necessary to have **at least** one success with probability at least $50\%$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of experiments necessary to have at least one success with probability at least $50\%$ can be calculated as  the number of experiments necessary to have no success with probability at most $50\%$.  This requires $(1-p)^n \le \frac12$ so $n  \ge \dfrac{\log 2}{- \log(1-p)}.$ With your example of $p=\frac{1}{10000}$ this gives $n\ge 6931.1$ (approximately, and you will round up to the next integer).

The number of experiments necessary to have exactly one success with probability at least $50\%$ requires $n p(1-p)^{n-1} \ge \frac{1}{2}$ and this will not have a closed form solution if you do not use something like Lambert-W functions.  But for small $p$ there will be no sensible solution to this anyway: in your example of $p=\frac{1}{10000}$, the maximum probability of exactly one success happens when $n=9999$ or $10000$ and is then about $36.78978\% \approx \exp(-1)$ which is too low to answer your question.

Comment: Are you saying that $\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k} = 1-(1-p)^n$ ?

Comment: Yes, I am, or was.  I deleted my answer because I had written a solution on the assumption you meant at least one success. It is often impossible to have a probability $\gt 50\%$ of **exactly** one success.  Basically, if we have a large enough sample to have a good chance of at least one success, chances are good we will have $2$ or more.

Comment: @diff_math Yes.  It obviously is.  Summing from k=0 to n is the probability of anything from no to all successes; which is $1$.  So if we subtract the probability of no success from $1$ we get the required probability of at least one success.

Comment: It seems that when I say there is no solution for small $p$, I mean $p \lt \frac12$. When $p=\frac12$ then $n=1$ or $2$ are solutions and when $p \gt \frac12$ then $n=1$ is a solution to your "exactly one" question

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I will rewrite my comment on the other answer, because this is what made me confused.
You can see my problem in this lines: suppose you have a die with 10000 sides numbered and pick one specfic side. How many times you should throw the die until you have at least $50\%$ of chance of coming up this side? I got a little confused about what to use: **at least** one success or **exactly** one success.

Comment: @diff_math: Your reformulated question also has the answer $6931.1\ldots$ rounded up.  So you needed to look for *at least* one success.

Comment: @Henry What about correcting the mess [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1427838/)?

Answer (score 5):

The number of successes in $n$ independent Bernoulli trials with probability of success $p$ is a binomial random variable $X$, such that $$\Pr[X = k] = \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}, \quad k = 0, 1, 2, \ldots, n.$$  Therefore, the probability of observing **at least one** success in one trial is the complement of the probability of observing **no** successes:  $$\Pr[X \ge 1] = 1 - \Pr[X = 0] = 1 - \binom{n}{0} p^0 (1-p)^{n-0} = 1 - (1-p)^n.$$  We then wish to find the minimum $n$ such that $$0.5 \le \Pr[X \ge 1] = 1 - (1-p)^n;$$ that is to say, $$n \ge -\frac{\log 2}{\log(1-p)} = \left\lceil -\frac{\log 2}{\log (1-p)} \right\rceil.$$  For $p = 10^{-4}$, this gives $n = 6932$ as you wrote.

---

If, however, you want the probability of **exactly** one success to be at least 50%, this would be $$0.5 \le \Pr[X = 1] = \binom{n}{1} p^1 (1-p)^{n-1} = np(1-p)^{n-1}.$$  The solution of this inequality does not have an elementary closed form for general $p \in (0,1)$ and positive integer $n$.  However, we can show that there is no solution to this inequality if $p < 0.44303\ldots$, since for a fixed $p \in (0,1)$, treating $n$ temporarily as a continuous positive real and differentiating $\Pr[X = 1]$ with respect to $n$, we can see that a local extremum occurs when $$n = -1/\log(1-p),$$ attaining $$\Pr[X = 1]_{\text{max}} \approx \frac{-p}{e(1-p)\log(1-p)}.$$  And this expression is less than $1/2$ for $p < 0.44303\ldots$.  Of course, $n$ is a positive integer, so this is just an approximation, but it remains the case that when $p$ is "small," no number of experiments will guarantee that the probability of **exactly** one success will exceed $0.5$.

Comment: You can see my problem in this lines: suppose you have a die with 10000 sides numbered and pick one specfic side. How many times you should throw the die until you have at least $50\%$ of chance of coming up this side? I got a little confused about what to use: **at least** one success or **exactly** one success.

Comment: My interpretation of the wording above is "at least one."

Comment: You can close the gap between your approximation $0.443$ and the true bound of $0.5$ by considering $n=1,2,3$

Comment: @diff_math That question is a completely different one to the binomial question!  You are using a binomial model when your actual model is **geometric**.  The fundamental difference is that in a binomial model, the number of trials is **fixed in advance**.  In your proposed experiment, you continue to conduct trials until you achieve success.

Comment: @Henry Indeed, I agree. I just didn't bother going through those last steps since the range of $p$ of interest is so much smaller.

Comment: heropup: the geometric distribution "until the first" question also leads to the $1−(1−p)^n \ge \frac12$ answer as the binomial "at least one" question

Comment: @Henry Yes, it does--but it does so in a way that avoids the problem of trying to decide whether we need *exactly* one success or *at least one* success.

Comment: I tried the geometric distribution but got confused. In this case, $X$ is the number of failures before the first success and $P(X=n) = p(1-p)^n$. With $p=1/10000$, we want to calculate $n$ such that $P(X=n) < 1/2$ ? I don't know how to interpret this condition.

Comment: I mean, how should I read $P(X=n) < 1/2$ ? The probability of having $n$ failures before the first success is smaller than $1/2$? How this connects to my problem is not clear to me. I want to talk about the probability of the first success, not the quantity of failures.