# How many simultaneous independent events needed to have a certain probability of getting at least X specific outcomes

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics

Each cup of coffee I purchase has random 60% probability of having my name spelled correctly on the cup. If I want to have an 80% chance of having at least $x$ correctly spelled coffee cups for my collection, how many coffees do I need to purchase?

I can afford an infinite number of coffees from my local coffee shop, but I can only make one order (all the cups will arrive at the same time).

I've seen [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1440254/how-many-experiments-we-should-run-to-have-one-success-with-probability-at-least) which feels related but I'm not sure how to extend that to desiring a certain number of successes.

Answer (score 1):

You can basically use the same technique as in the linked post. If you purchase n cups of coffee, the number of cups with your name correctly spelled on it has binomial distribution $X\sim \mathscr B(n, .6)$. We are interested in the probability that the number of cups purchased with your name correctly spelled on it is at least x, that is, $P(X\ge x)$. We know for a binomial distribution this is $\sum_{k=x}^{n}P(X=k)$. And we want this quantity to be greater than $80\%$, that is, getting at least x cups with your name correctly spelled with a probability of at least $80\%$. You simply find the smallest n such that $\sum_{k=x}^n{n\choose k}.6^k.4^{n-k}\ge .8$. This can be done using the pbinom command. If, for example, you wanted to find the number of cups you should purchase to have at least 80% chance of getting 5 cups with your name spelled right, you would find

```
> print(pbinom(4, 9, .6, lower.tail=FALSE))
[1] 0.7334323
```

but

```
> print(pbinom(4, 10, .6, lower.tail=FALSE))
[1] 0.8337614
```

therefore you need to buy 10 cups to have the probability of getting at least 5 cups with your name spelled right to be at least 80%. More generally, you can use the following code to find the number of purchases needed

```
cupsrightname=5
for (k in 1:100) {
  w=pbinom(cupsrightname-1, k, .6, lower.tail=FALSE)
  if (w>=.8) {
    print(k)
    break
  }
}
```

-out

```
[1] 10
```