# Determining if a random variable is lognormal

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm struggling to understand a part of the solution to this question: If $X$ and $Y$ are lognormal random variables, is their product $XY$ lognormally distributed?

The solution I have suggests looking at $ln(XY) = ln(X) + ln(Y)$. However, it says that $XY$ being lognormal depends on if $ln(X)$ and $ln(Y)$ are joint Normal. That is, $ln(X) + ln(Y)$ may not be normally distributed even if they are individually normally distributed implying $XY$ will not be lognormal.

But I don't understand how $ln(X) + ln(Y)$ could be possibly non-Normal if each of them are Normal, as the sum of two normals is a normal.

Comment: Your final assertion *"the sum of two normals is a normal"* need not be true.

Comment: @Henry: Are you sure? Please provide a counter example.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: I have already given a counterexample in the answers: "Suppose $W \sim N(0,1)$, $S=1$ when $|W| \lt 1$, and $S=-1$ when $|W| \ge 1$. Then $V=SW $ is also normally distributed as $N(0,1)$ but $|W+V| \lt 2$ so in this case the sum $W+V$ is not normally distributed."

Comment: I already found it :-)

Answer (score 1):

The sum of two *joint* normal distributed random variables is again normal.

It is important that the random variables are actually joint normal, as the assertion can fail otherwise. The classical example is the following:

Let $X$ and $Z$ be independent random variables, where $X$ is standard Gaussian and $Z$ is Rademacher distributed, i.e. $P(Z = 1) = P(Z = -1) = \frac{1}{2}$.

Then the random variables $X$ and $Y = ZX$ are both normal [and even uncorrelated!], but their sum isn't normal since $P(X + Y = 0) = P(X(Z + 1) = 0) = P(Z=-1)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question *If $X$ and $Y$ are lognormal random variables, is their product $XY$ lognormally distributed?*.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: The question asks the following: If $\ln(X)$ and $\ln(Y)$ is normal, is $\ln (XY) = \ln(x) + \ln(Y)$ also normal? I've answered this question with a "no", I just took the liberty of renaming the random variables,

Answer (score -1):

As a counter-example to your statement that the "sum of two normals is a normal":

Suppose $W \sim N(0,1)$, $S=1$ when $|W| \lt 1$, and $S=-1$ when $|W| \ge 1$. Then $V=SW $ is also normally distributed as $N(0,1)$ but $|W+V| \lt 2$ so in this case the sum $W+V$ is not normally distributed.

Comment: Your reasoning might need to be adjusted, depending on the definition of a normal distribution. In the "proper" definition of a normal distribution, a constant random variable $c$ is said to be $\mathcal{N}(c, 0)$. This means that it isn't enoug to show that a random variable is bounded in order to show that it isn't normal. If you don't adefine constant random variables to be normal, the random variables $Y = -X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ are a simpler counterexample.

Comment: @Dominik: This particular bounded example is non-zero with probability over $0.68$, but is $0$ with probability over $0.31$ so it is certainly not normally distrinuted

Comment: @Henry What about correcting the mess [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1427838/)?